# Is there any plugin in Android Studio to create Layout Sub folders?

Tags: android, android-studio

I know in android studio you can not create layout subfolders as shown below.

```
layout
    -subfolder1
        --layout.xml
        --layut2.xml
    -subfolder2
        --layout3.xml
```

Is there any third party plugin in android Studio which gives the above functionality?

Answer (score 5):

you can do like this! By adding your folder paths in main{ }.

[Source: Click here!](https://plus.google.com/+DmytroDanylyk/posts/bjYgPZFK1ti)

[image]